# code within if/else statement in do/while loop

Tags: java, arrays, function, loops, while-loop

So heres my code and im running on repl.it and theres an error when I get to the do while loop at in the main code. No loop works inside the main code even when I don't use any of the functions within the loop. So for example I tried a simple while loop with if/else just display random things that were completely unrelated to my actual code but still get the same errors. If anyone knows what I did wrong here, please let me know.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {

  static int[] get_marks(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<>();
    final int FLAG = -1;
    int entries = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter your marks. Type -1 when done.");

    while (entries != FLAG){
    entries = input.nextInt();
    
    if (entries >=0 && entries <= 100){
      marks.add(entries);
    } else if (entries == FLAG) {
      break;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Invalid entry. Marks must be between 0-100.");
      }
    }
    input.close();

    int[] array = new int[marks.size()];
    for (int i=0; i < marks.size(); i++){
      array[i] = marks.get(i);
    }
    return array;
  }

  static int[] frequency(int[] marks_main){
    
    int[] marks_freq = new int[101];

    for(int i=0; i<marks_main.length; i++){
      marks_freq[marks_main[i]] += 1;
    }
    return marks_freq;
  }

  static int mode(int modeList[], int[] marks_main) {
    int maxValue = 0, maxCount = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < marks_main.length; ++i) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < marks_main.length; ++j) {
          if (modeList[j] == modeList[i])
           count = count + 1;
         }

         if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = modeList[i];
         }
      }
      return maxValue;
   }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String SENTINEL = "Done", A = "Frequency", B = "Mode";
    String user_input; 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
     int[] marks_main = get_marks();
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(marks_main));

    do {
    
      System.out.println("Which would you like to use? Type " + A + " for Frequency or " + B + " for Mode");
      user_input = input.next();

      if (user_input.equalsIgnoreCase(A)){
        int[] frequencylist = frequency(marks_main);
        for (int i=0; i<=100; i++){
        System.out.println(i +" : " + frequencylist[i]);
        }
      } else if (user_input.equalsIgnoreCase(B)){
        int modeList[] = marks_main;
        System.out.println("Mode is "+ mode(modeList,marks_main));
      } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
      }

      System.out.println("Would you like to run the program again? If not, type " + SENTINEL);
      user_input = input.next();
    } while (!user_input.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL));
    input.close();

    System.out.println("Thanks for using my program!");
    
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove `input.close()`. That **also** closes `System.in`

Comment: thanks. you saved my program